# minimize a batch file and firefox while running

Tags: windows, firefox, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Am tryinging to create a batch file that will be scheduled by windows task scheduler
.here is  my code

```
start /min test.bat
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  -tray
TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe
```

however running this in task scheduller causes a bug that runs indefinately which is not desireable.My  goal is to run the firefox and the cmd minimized.
Using this code with task scheduler works

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  -tray
 TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe
```

fine however the firefox and cmd are not minimized.What am i doing wrong?is there a tweek arround it?

Comment: Maybe try `start /min "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`?

Comment: Hm. `start /min notepad.exe` works perfectly for me, while Firefox doesn't seem to want to start minimized.

Comment: what of the bat file can you try starting it minimized ,i runs indefinately when run with task scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acctually do this by using an external command line tool.Its called nircmd at it works like charm.Here is a how i did it `"nircmd.exe" win hide process "firefox.exe"` here is a complete doc on its usage  [nircmd doc](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

Answer (score 1):

Short version: You can't do that.

Long Version: When someone makes an application, ie. firefox, the entry point of the program is `Winmain()` which has several parameters given to it by Windows. The fourth parameter is the only one that matters for this. It tells the program how Windows wants it to open. (How you tell Windows to open it) Later in the program, when the window is actually shown with the `showWindow()` function, the second parameter tells how the programmer wants the window to be displayed. The programmer can then either send it the fourth parameter windows filled for us in the `Winmain()` function (How you want it displayed), or he can explicitly tell it how he wants it to open (eg. maximized). If the programmer does this, it doesn't matter how you tell the program to open, because it never uses this variable.

Comment: helpful but i found a work around on how to do this.Its actually possible to start the program minimized ,maximized ,hidden or whatever variable is ok with you...here is a link to the doc [link](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) ..

Comment: I didn't know that kind of thing existed. That's nice to know