# Batch file to start browser minimized and kill it after

Tags: batch-file

Trying to create a batch file that will open a specific browser (firefox) minimized and direct it to a link. After A specific period 5 seconds the browser will close. I can direct to the link open a specific browser but the browser does not start minimized nor does it close after 5.

```
@echo off

SET BROWSER=firefox.exe
SET WAIT_TIME=2
start /min %BROWSER% http://www.stackoverflow.com
SET WAIT_TIME=2
taskkill /IM firefox.exe
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [minimize a batch file and firefox while running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763548/minimize-a-batch-file-and-firefox-while-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch file cannot close the process because, while it sets a variable called `WAIT_TIME`, the batch file does not actually wait; the `taskkill` command runs immediately, before the process has even started.  You need to add a command such as `timeout` to actually make the batch file wait.

```
SET WAIT_TIME=2
timeout %WAIT_TIME%
taskkill /im firefox.exe
```

For the minimized window, there is no good solution.  A Windows (non-console) program receives the `/min` param through its `nCmdShow` parameter to `WinMain()`, but it's up to the program what to do with that.  Most simply ignore it.  There are 3rd-party solutions which will send a minimize command to the window after it has opened, but there's no easy way to do this in Windows Batch without involving another scripting language like VBS or PowerShell.

Comment: Indeed.  I think a better solution for OP would be to invoke the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object to navigate to the web page hidden, wait till `obj.readyState == 4`, sleep 5 seconds, then close.  I don't feel like writing it though.

Comment: I see what I did wrong with kill, thanks for explaining that. As for minimize I might be able to work around it with the page settings but thanks anyway.